# AttributeError:'module' object has no attribute 'call' :Python

Tags: python

I am new to python and not knowing whats going on here. I have tried searching a lot but had to end up asking here

I am trying to learn subprocess which executes a simple command as:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['ls'])
```

Now, when I run the program I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "subprocess.py", line 1, in <module>
   import subprocess
File "/task/subprocess.py", line 2, in <module>
subprocess.call(['ls'])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'call'
```

Comment: Look at your traceback more closely.. what is being imported here?

Comment: Because you've called your file `subprocess.py`, you import it instead of the real subprocess.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You called your file `subprocess.py`, change then name and you will be ok. You are trying to import from your file and not the module

Comment: But then its giving me a new error(though i dont have a file called subprocess.py)  File "/task/subprocess.py", line 4, in <module>
    #
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_output'

Comment: what is `/task/subprocess.py`

Comment: do you have a `task/subprocess.pyc` file?

Answer (score 0):

ldap-new:~ # rm -rf  subprocess.pyc

This worked for me i just removed .pyc file and run again

Regards,
-Mansur